# Why is using lucene's DateRangeField substantially increasing index size?

Tags: solr, lucene

Recently, I added three DateRangeField's to my solr schema.  This quadrupled the size of the index-- specifically the .doc file.  The fields are used heavily in that they are present in all the documents and the ranges can be quite large, but this still seems like a surprising increase.  I checked the index with Luke, and I see a large number of terms that might correspond to the size of the ranges.  This seems supported by the fact that the term counts remain consistent even when I index a very small number of documents.

Is this expected behavior?  Is there some way to improve the index size and still use DateRangeField?

This is using Solr 6.6.

Many thanks.

Comment: A date range is in effect indexed as a tree with spatial information - i.e. there will be a larger number of tokens generated to support the different levels of specificity of the query. A 3x increase seems excessive, but if you have many ranges and small documents otherwise, it'll affect the size in a larger way than otherwise. Then the next question instead becomes: is a 3x in size an issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, this increase is a show stopper for me.  I actually only need "year" ranges, but documentation seemed to state that the DateRangeField was still the way to go.  Do you think indexing mins and maxes with IntPoint fields and doing all the work in the query would be better? @MatsLindh

Comment: Do you have any examples of which queries you need to get answers to and how your input data looks? Add them to your question. It might be viable to do it as ints, but remember that it might be harder to do if you have multivalued start/end fields. Add examples of how you want to query the data and how many entries for start/end there can be.